# 403 Forbidden error on WAMP Server

Tags: localhost, wamp

I'm working with WAMP Server. I found a problem on loading some images through WAMP.

I added png files to my images folder and when I tried to open those files, error occurs:

```
Forbidden You don't have permission to access /resources/images/3.png on this server.
```

but if I add some other png or jpg files to the same folder, it works.

I don't understand why this error occurs to  some files only. Those files are processed using a *MAC OS*.

Comment: Is the resources folder actually in your root folder or did you mean to code 'resources/images/3.png`

Comment: Yes, they are in the root folder..!!

Answer (score 0):

If your `resources` folder is for example `c:\resources\images\` then by default Apache will not know it has access to that folder.

In your httpd.conf file you should have something like this:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

This is for security, and denys access to all folder on the drive Apache is installed on, ( I assume thats C: )
**Dont change that set of instructions** they are there for a good reason!! **SECURITY**

You should also have something like this:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1 localhost
</Directory>
```

Which allows Apache to access files in the specified folder and subfolders

Now because your resuorces folder is not inside that structure you will need to add another set of instructions to allow Apache access to this other folder. Something like this:

```
<Directory "c:/resources/images/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1 localhost
</Directory>
```

I have assumed you are only working locally and not yet given access to the world, but if you want to `Allow from all` you will also have to do that for your `resources` folder.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM: I had similar problem with a file created from other computer (a css in my case). To solve the problem I read that it is necessary to change the permissions but I don't know to do this on Windows so I try this alternative:

SOLUTION: Open the file, copy the content and paste it in a new file, this makes sure the permissions are ok.

When changing the name by using F2 it didn't work for me, I believe it is because the permissions where still the same.